# Is it possible to use custom page sizes with printing PDF's via an Electron app?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, printing, electron

I really do apologise if this has been asked before, but I cannot find much information for the implementation I require for ElectronJS for my prior research before getting stuck into coding.

I'm wanting to develop a simple app that a user inputs a 7 character string that is able to be printed via laser or thermal printer.

The width of the printing material size is not the issue, the length of the material is.

I have a 20" long piece of printing material, longer than a standard A4 page. My problem is that most printers only accept standardised paper size such as A4, A3, A5, etc.

Is there anyway to silently print onto the longer page in a single print-process? As it stands, most printing processes in the likes of Illustrator will spool 2 pages to fit the content onto the sheet.

I have looked into libraries such as [this](https://github.com/artiebits/pdf-to-printer) but to no avail.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Split the input onto enough pages of A4 paper or are you trying to literally print onto a roll of paper using "standard" printers?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I'm trying to print onto a sheet that's 520mm in length and 111mm in width using a standard printer. 

We have software in my workplace that does this just fine with a standard laser jet printer so I know it's possible. However, is this achievable in Electron to print a PDF (520x111mm) in a single spool and not split it over two pages? So yes, print onto a single roll of paper if possible.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I don't suppose you're able to give me a yes or no to this question? You seem to be well versed in the Electron universe.

Comment: As I've seen past questions on this topic, no, you can't do this with standard Electron APIs (or Chrome's, for that matter) -- they require use of a well-known paper size. You might get away with directly printing via the OS' capabilities from the Main Process though. I'd take a look at [`ipp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipp), but I currently do not have the capabilities to test this enough to provide an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Thanks for the reply, Alex. Time to look into another avenue for my project.